# Sql injection vulnerability

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I'm not some kind of hax0r or so, but my boss has a website and I told him that it was vulnerable to sql injection attacks. He then responded that it was not a danger, because all the information is public; so I told him that there is the possibility to drop the tables.

Usually the DROP table command works, can someone tell me why not in this case?
NOTE: THIS DATABASE ONLY STORES NEWS, NOT VITAL INFO!

```
news.php?id=-99%20union%20all%20select%201,2,3,4,5%20from%20information_schema.columns%20where%20table_schema=0x656e6469616d615--
```

Please, do not reply with hax0r-hate comments, if I wanted to know how to hack I would be on irc channels, not here.

EDIT: 
If he's safe from database editing I think he's right.
He could disclose the sql query but that would defeat the purpose of showing him the danger is real.

Comment: You'll need to show the code that executes the SQL

Comment: I don't think my boss will take that seriously, because that way the website really is secure, the preak will never have access to the database query format. I found the column name, table name and database name.
Can i tell my boss the website is secure to information violation?

Comment: @KerrekSB - Yo dawg, I heard you like websites so I put a website on your website so you could like at websites while on your website.

Comment: thanks guys, really ;)
Edited the first topic. If it's secure, just tell me. I will blame you if you're wrong lol. Actually, i can't tell them i have an account at stackOF, as he would know the main knowledge comes from here ihih.

Comment: I'd count any disclosure of information as dangerous - if this doesn't get fixed now, what happens in the future when/if more sensitive information is placed onto that database?

SQL Injection is very easy to protect against, and if you know of a possible vulnerability it should be fixed ASAP, regardless of what is deemed sensitive. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are able to detect columns names from SQL injections, it means it is violatable.

It also means you could easily brute force attack a webpage and detect all the structure, users, export the data, etc... So yeah, site IS vulnerable and it goes much farther than "My data is public so i don't care"...

The hacker could find a way to insert data into the database, create some phishing, steal data from XSS attacks that he inserts into the database. There are tons of reasons to take this seriously. SQL injection doesn't mean that the hacker can only read your data, it can lead to serious compromises...

Comment: Beat me to it - well said! :)

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, actually, this database only stores NEWS, not vital info, but would be very bad if editable. 
That answer was very enlightening, if you don't mind i'll use your words as mine :P , i'll give you the points you deserve.

Answer (score 3):

I'd count any disclosure of information as dangerous - if this doesn't get fixed now, what happens in the future when/if more sensitive information is placed onto that database? What if existing data is modified in a malicious fashion?

SQL Injection is very easy to protect against, and if you know of a possible vulnerability it should be fixed ASAP, regardless of what is deemed sensitive. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection isn't a problem if the SQL user only has access to the SELECT privilege. Any other privileges could probably be a security threat (Particullarly DROP, but also INSERT or DELETE).

Personally, I would just protect it all against SQL injection, and then apply privilleges to the SQL user that restrict the ability to perform an attack even if my front line of defences is broken.

Even if the data is not sensitive, SQL injection could lead to phishing attacks, scams, and illegal content being displayed on the vulnerable website. Not good.